# one signal send notification through api

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I want to add a device(user) through api. the user is inserted in one signal successfully but when I try to send a notification this user or all user which is added through API is receiving any notification.
here is code of adding device(user):

```
$fields = [
            'app_id' => "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
            'device_type'  => 5,
            'identifier'   => 'ce777617da7f548fe7a9ab6febb56cf39fba6d382000c0395666288d961ee566',
            'timezone'     => '18000',
            'game_version' => '1.1',
            'device_os'    => '87',
            'device_model' => "Win32",
            'sdk' => "151105",
            ];

        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

but when add the device(user) through the default subscribe button in one signal, and then send a notification to this device through API it received notification.

**here are both device parameters which I saved
The first one is through API which is not working and 2nd is through the default javascript subscribe button which is working**

```
(
                    [id] => xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
                    [identifier] => YjYyNzliZWYtMjJhNC00M2JhLThlYmQtNjY2ZjcyYmFmMzc5
                    [session_count] => 1
                    [language] => en
                    [timezone] => 18000
                    [game_version] => 1.1
                    [device_os] => 87
                    [device_type] => 5
                    [device_model] => Win32
                    [ad_id] => 
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [last_active] => 1609523086
                    [playtime] => 0
                    [amount_spent] => 0
                    [created_at] => 1609523086
                    [invalid_identifier] => 
                    [badge_count] => 0
                    [sdk] => 151105
                    [test_type] => 
                    [ip] => 39.37.185.28
                    [external_user_id] => 
                )

         

(
                [id] => xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
                [identifier] => https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/e08NnzE3H40:APA91bGy3BnmRPDkEGDMH_33GgZBaDxYbdCxr17dIml1iJyn0VtWovlIgNS9Zq1yJZPCUSN-HEyGkVHashrZk_dNAmSgKKjXOxDs7xP2xPAOOedmZicwGaWx3fugd2Fov0ZZNR40hQw_
                [session_count] => 1
                [language] => en
                [timezone] => 18000
                [game_version] => 
                [device_os] => 87
                [device_type] => 5
                [device_model] => Win32
                [ad_id] => 
                [tags] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [last_active] => 1609523217
                [playtime] => 0
                [amount_spent] => 0
                [created_at] => 1609523217
                [invalid_identifier] => 
                [badge_count] => 0
                [sdk] => 151105
                [test_type] => 
                [ip] => 39.37.185.28
                [external_user_id] => 
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Laravel notification channels to help you with this. There is a OneSignal channel that you can use to access the OneSignal APIs.

https://laravel-notification-channels.com/onesignal/